# How to upload a jar file to ooyala-spark job server from java

Tags: java, curl

Currently we can upload a jar to the ooyala-spark job server by the below curl command from command line:

```
$curl --data-binary @job-server-tests/target/job-server-tests-0.4.0.jar localhost:8090/jars/test
```

I want to upload the same via java code and not the curl command. I tried using many HTTP/Apache rest clients, but am not able to successfully submit the jar.

URL for ooyala-spark job server- https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver

Comment: The jar is uploaded to the job server as a POST request with the jar file, and name (can be seen from the curl command ). So I would need a java rest client which can do the same to the ooyala spark job server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/bluebreezecf/SparkJobServerClient).
This is not bad library, which can you help to submit job from java code.

You can do something like this:

```
  ISparkJobServerClient client = null;
    try {
        client = SparkJobServerClientFactory.getInstance().createSparkJobServerClient("http://ip:8090/");

        Map<String, String> jobParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jobParams.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_APP_NAME, "job-name");
        jobParams.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_CLASS_PATH, "com.spark.job.WorldCountExample");

        SparkJobResult result = client.startJob("param1=\"data1\", param2=\"data2\"", jobParams);

        SparkJobResult jobResult = client.getJobResult(result.getJobId())

    } catch (SparkJobServerClientException e) {
        System.out.println(e)
    }finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.stop();
        }
```

**Note**, that this is a async job.

Comment: Thanks a lot James for this post!!

Comment: no problems :) if my answer correct, please, approve it.